# source for using יי (two yuds) as Hashem's name?

Tags: shemos-sacred-names

When did the use of two yuds becone a כינוי for the שם הוי"ה? 
Is this perhaps the two yuds of "יאהדונהי"?
What's the source for using this abbreviation in place of other shemos in davening?

Comment: Nice Q. Do you want to know in general how that "abbreviation" was created, or are you asking specifically why that's used in davening, only? If you're asking generally, please delete your last question.